# javafx scene builder - circular graphics for the radio button menu item and square boxes for the check box menu item invisible in the application

Tags: javafx, fonts, text-editor, scenebuilder

I am creating a text editor using the gluon scene builder with java fx. The scene builder version is SceneBuilder-10.0.0 used with java version "10.0.1". I have a project to build a Text Editor. While building the components in the scene builder,  (Please see image)

[image: Scenebuilder scene]

I have a file menu and a font menu. Under the Font menu, I have radio button menu items (monospaced, serif, sans-serif) and checkbox menu items (italic, bold). The application does not show the circular graphics next to the radio button menu item names, neither does it show the square graphics next to the checkbox menu item names. They operate perfectly, except for the invisible graphical representation (circle for radio buttons and boxes for checkboxes) next to the menu item names. What can I do to make these show-up? What properties do I need to modify in the scene-builder?

Please see the image for the comparison of the missing graphics and the one with the graphics. The left side is what I have and I want it to look like the right side.

[image: Comparison of the missing graphics and the one with the graphics].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously too late for you, but since I came across your question while asking myself the same thing:

```
    Menu fontMenu = new Menu("Font");
    CheckBox bold = new CheckBox("Bold");
    bold.setSelected(false);
    bold.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    RadioButton italic = new RadioButton("Italic");
    italic.setSelected(true);
    italic.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
    CustomMenuItem boldMenu = new CustomMenuItem(bold);
    CustomMenuItem italicMenu = new CustomMenuItem(italic);
    fontMenu.getItems().addAll(boldMenu, italicMenu);
```

Hope all is well!

Comment: ahh .. after a quick test I understand (both your answer and OP's problem): it's the not showing if not selected, right? That's probably a styling issue and might be handled in css (didn't try that, though).

Comment: @user3889361: I think I know what mistake I did now. In the SceneBuilder for JavaFX, I selected the buttons from Menu instead of Controls. The CheckBox and RadioButton are in the Control section. And in my program, I used the CheckMenuItem & RadioMenuItem from the Menu section. I am going to try this out. Hopefully, it works. Thanks a lot for replying. I appreciate it. Better late than never.

Comment: @Sam Vitare I tried to do this with scene builder to begin with and realized it wasn't working out. It is likely possible though. Sorry for answering on just how to build it with code. I hope it worked out :)

Comment: @KaitlinRenee No worries. I haven't made the changes as yet with the scene builder, but I am going to try this out and will update my status then. Whatever information provided always helps. I appreciate it. Thanks!